# QT check if interface is real

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I am tryng to get the mac adress using QT. Right now I am using this code:

```
QStringList Util::getMac(){
QStringList items;

foreach(QNetworkInterface interface, QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces())
{
   if (interface.flags().testFlag(QNetworkInterface::IsRunning))
     foreach (QNetworkAddressEntry entry, interface.addressEntries())
     {
       if (interface.hardwareAddress() != "00:00:00:00:00:00" && entry.ip().toString().contains(".")){
         items << interface.hardwareAddress();
       }
     }
}
return items;}
```

But the problem is that it also gives me mac adress of a hamachi interface. So is there any way to check if that interface is internet-accessible? Like that I would know that it is real and not virtual.

Comment: Even "real" interfaces can sometimes not reach the internet. Additionally, in cases where you're running over a VPN, that VPN interface _is_ the interface you want to use. Perhaps it would be useful to compare your default gateway to the combination of ip addresses and subnet masks on the interfaces you're iterating over to determine which interface is the network that goes to the internet?

Comment: thats a good idea, thank you. The only problem is with getting default gateway ip. It is platform specific, and I did not find a solution for every platform I need

Comment: I need to for the UUID, so it does not matter if that real interface is not able to connect to the internet

Comment: In that case, this is an entirely different question that has been answered in other places. I recommend you look at this link http://serverfault.com/questions/40712/what-range-of-mac-addresses-can-i-safely-use-for-my-virtual-machines

Comment: I mean I need to know the mac adress, so my program may use it as a unique PC id. I do not need to assign one.

Comment: Yes, I know. Do you understand how MAC addresses work? The first 24 bytes are a vendor ID. If your NIC driver is reporting that its vendor is in the range of a locally-assigned address... ..then using some lateral thinking...

Answer (score 0):

You could check the IP of the Interface via http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkinterface.html#allAddresses and then see if it is an address that can connect to the internet

Comment: I know how to get its ip... but how do I know if that ip is able to connect to the internet?

Comment: @black You're all over the map. If all you are interested in is making a UID from the MAC (not always the best practice, but it can work), then you don't really care if you're able to reach the Internet. Or ANY network, for that matter.

Comment: @black That's true, but this has _NOTHING_ to do with Internet reachability. Do you understand the OSI model well, and how it is used in a system?

Comment: Well, I do know it, but not perfectly.